# Postgres Position function for whole phrases? String search

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there a way to use position or another function to find strings in a field but not have it be part of another word? For example if I am looking for the word "bench" with position I would do something like this

```
 POSITION('bench' IN products)
```

The products column would look something like this

```
 **Products**
 tool bench
 benchpress
 park bench
 benchmark
 bench heater
 utility bench tool
```

I only want to match the rows where bench is NOT part of another word (don't want to match benchpress or benchmark). Thank you

Comment: Trim the column to avoid before and after spaces . then write a case if there is a space then only check for existence (charindex function) else ignore.

Comment: Please use CTE (with clause) for next time to make responders concentrate on answer rather than formatting sample input. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use `\y` regex expression ([word boundary matcher](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#POSIX-CONSTRAINT-ESCAPES-TABLE)):

```
with t(word) as (values
  ('tool bench'),
  ('benchpress'),
  ('park bench'),
  ('benchmark'),
  ('bench heater'),
  ('utility bench tool')
)
select *
from t
where word ~ '\ybench\y'
```

[Dbfiddle here.](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9tza9C9kyneatwSJK1Ki8G/0)

Answer (score 0):

using the with clause from Tomáš Záluský you can simple use a like condition searching for *is there a space before and after it, is there a space after it or is there a space before*

```
with t(word) as (values
  ('tool bench'),
  ('benchpress'),
  ('park bench'),
  ('benchmark'),
  ('bench heater'),
  ('utility bench tool')
)
select *
from t
where word  like '% bench %' or word like 'bench %'  or word like  '% bench'
```

or you can split your string to an array, using space as delemiter and look, if there is a fitting element

```
 with t(word) as (values
      ('tool bench'),
      ('benchpress'),
      ('park bench'),
      ('benchmark'),
      ('bench heater'),
      ('utility bench tool')
    )
    select * from t 
where string_to_array(word, ' ') @> array[ 'bench' ]
```

or you also can use postgres and its textsearch

```
with t(word) as (values
  ('tool bench'),
  ('benchpress'),
  ('park bench'),
  ('benchmark'),
  ('bench heater'),
  ('utility bench tool')
)
SELECT 
* from t 
where to_tsvector('english', word) @@ to_tsquery('english', 'bench')
```

so choose the right for your task, wich fits best and is fastest.